# How to get DJANGO obtain my dht11 or mlx90614 infrared reading sensor value on webpage?

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi

I'm stuck at the moment, please give me a lead for dealing this matter !!
I got the codes for both sensors, but I'm not sure how to connect it with the django framework...

My idea basically is

Sensor -> Raspberry pi -> Django -> Website

Answer (score 0):

Django is really intended for interfacing between a webserver and a database, with the implication that the server may be quite busy with multiple requests. It may be too much of a "heavyweight"  solution, depending on your bigger picture.

One way would be to implement a data logging service. At appropriate intervals, the Pi would POST its latest readings to Django running on a server, which would store the reading in a database table (and possibly prune that table so that old data gets thinned out or deleted). So you'd implement two simple views. A logger view that the Pi would send data to, and a user view that would retrieve the latest readings (or more advanced, generate a graph of the readings over the last sensible time span).

You might well have to consider a security mechanism to make sure that only the Pi can log data, depending on whether you have to worry about hostile users/hackers or not.

This would scale up to a site-wide installation of a plurality of sensor-control Pi systems all logging their data to the same server and database.

The other way to go would be to implement a lightweight web server on the Pi itself, with a view interface (and possibly a privileged manager interface). I have a commercial data-logger for a bunch of room temperature and humidity sensors that works this way. The code frameworks exist: Flask, for example. I Googled and found this [Build a Python Web Server With Flask](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/python-web-server-with-flask) on a Raspberry Pi. At this point my further  useful knowledge drops to zero.

Comment: Thank you for the comment :D ! I will try look on it !